# Formal argument cannot be a global variable

Tags: ruby, algorithm, path-finding

I'm currently working on a pathfinder algorithm and I'm using Ruby (RGSS3) language where I have a function  **find_path (startx,starty,destx,desty, $game_player)**

- startx: X coordinate of the starting position
- starty: Y coordinate of the starting position
- destx: X coordinate of the desired position
- desty: Y coordinate of the starting position
- $game_player: Player's current X and Y coordinates

Sadly, it throws a [SyntaxError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qm30S.jpg) message, since I can't pass global variables as formal arguments.

I've tried to make a local variable (character_position = $game_player) just before I call the find_path() function, but then a [different error occurs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K50Rm.jpg), so the function can't see the variable.

The other day I found a solution to this problem; I made the character_position variable not before, but inside the find_path() funcion, and it seems like working, but I don't really know how and why.

*Working solution: find_path(startx, starty, destx, desty, character_position = $game_player)*

Can somebody explain what's happening there? Is there a cleaner, more elegant solution?

Comment: If $game_player is global you don't need to pass that variable into a function or method, just use it out

Comment: Same error occurs, similar my "local variable before the function" case, so the function cannot see it somehow.

Answer (score 1):

What you have here:

```
 find_path(startx, starty, destx, desty, character_position = $game_player)
```

is `$game_player` set as a *default value* for the argument. If you pass a different value for the fifth argument, it will be used instead. If you omit the fifth argument, the default value (the global) will be used. Keep in mind that unassigned globals don't raise NoMethodError upon reference, so if you don't define the global and don't pass a fifth argument, the value in the function will be nil.

If you don't want to allow custom values for `character_position` to be allowed, you can remove the argument and just reference `$game_player` directly from the function body.

In general, it's a good idea to avoid many globals if you can help it, but without seeing more of the code it's hard to advise on this.

Comment: That's not what OP has. OP has `def find_path(startx,starty,destx,desty, $game_player)` (I'm inferring the `def`)—not a default, just an argument. (The rest of your answer is accurate.)

Comment: @JordanRunning read the entire question. That is their "working solution" which they don't understand why it works.

Comment: I see what you mean. You might want to clarify that your first few sentences refer not to OP's initial problem statement ("it throws a SyntaxError"), but rather what they discuss later in their question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you aren't showing all of the code and what you really have is:

```
def find_path(startx, starty, destx, desty, $game_player)
```

This is a method *definition* and the names `startx`, `starty`, etc. are *argument names* for the method. Arguments are placeholders for data that will be provided later when the `find_path` method is actually run.

The problem is that `$game_player` is not an argument name, it is a global that actually represents some data somewhere in your script. Ruby is expecting a list of names, but you're giving it data!

When you change it to this, the meaning is entirely different:

```
def find_path(startx, starty, destx, desty, character_position = $game_player)
```

Now you're giving it an argument name `character_position`, so everything is OK. The `= $game_player` means that *when the method is run*, if data isn't provided for the `character_position` argument, `$game_player` will be used instead.

Comment: Note that up until (and including) Ruby 1.8, block argument binding used assignment semantics, and thus block parameters could be *anything* that was legal on the left hand side of an assignment, including instance variables, class variables, global variables, and even setters! In Ruby 1.8, what the OP wants to do can be achieved with `define_method(:find_path) {|startx, starty, destx, desty, $game_player| … }`. Although I'm still not sure why someone would want to do that.